# How to use pg_restore without upgrading Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I tried to restore a database from the command line using

```
pg_restore --host localhost --port 5434 __username "postgres" --dbname "database_name" -- verbose ""file_path"
```

But I keep getting the same message

> pg_restore archiver unsupported version (1.13) in file header

BTW: I'm using Postgres 9.6

Is there another way to solve it without upgrading PostgreSQL?

Comment: What is the postgres version where the backup was taken ? is the same where you are trying to restore 9.6 ?

Comment: You either need to re-take the dump with an older version of pg_dump, or do the restore with a newer version of pg_restore.

Comment: @AdelinoSilva It was taken from postgres 9.6
I tried with Postgres 13 and it works